# Is there an email directory of police departments and sheriffs offices for submitting FOI requests?

Tags: united-states, police, email, foia, public-records

I have been doing research related to FOI (Freedom of Information) fees and itemized invoices in particular. In this effort I have been contacting a number of departments and offices (ideally all) in the USA. I will submit a typical request and ask for a breakdown of the fees in the case there is a bill or estimate.

Does any website have an existing directory of emails for police departments and sheriffs offices? Records officers or otherwise.

Mainly FOIA email directories seem to be searchable, but I cannot find anything on local or state level requests.

The best guess I could think of was muckrock. They seem to have emails for every agency, but isn't there a publicly available list somewhere?

Could I make a FOI request to various departments and build a list?

Comment: "Is there an email directory of police departments and sheriffs offices for submitting FOI requests?" Pretty sure that the answer is "no."